# Making Thumbnails Change the Image Displayed on a Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a (primary) slider (showing mostly images - one at a time) on the bottom of which is another slider of thumbnails. I am trying to make the thumbnails such that clicking on one automatically display that image on the primary slider. The jQuery I used to do that is as follows (jump to the last function):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        main_slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            speed: 500,
            adaptiveHeight: true,
            video: true,
            auto: true,
            autoHover: true,
            autoControls: true,
            autoControlsCombine: true
        });
        thumb_slider = $('.thumbnailslider').bxSlider({
            slideWidth: 40,
            minSlides: 2,
            maxSlides: 15,
            slideMargin: 2
        });

        this_slider_index = $('.bxslider project_gallery_view gallery_project_display a.main_display').attr("href");

        $('.thumbnailslider a.bx-clone').click( function(){
            $('.thumbnailslider a.bx-clone').attr("href", this_slider_index)
        });
});
```

What I'm doing here is making an on-click function for each thumbnail of the thumbnail class. I then set the href attribute of each to the index of each image in the primary slider. However, my sliders act as if this function doesn't exist, which means that I'm clearly missing something. I've tried searching for solutions for hours, but cannot figure out what I did wrong here. 
(Disclaimer: I'm not very familiar with jQuery either, so please forgive me if it's something obvious.)

Comment: i don't see you do it for each. you apply one same href for all of elements in array that returned by this query $('.thumbnailslider a.bx-clone')

Comment: Where should I be adding .each in my function?

Comment: Should the each be added like this:
 this_slider_index = $('.bxslider project_gallery_view gallery_project_display a.main_display').each.attr("href");

I tried that, but it doesn't work either. :/

Comment: can you write down logic of sctipt by steps in simpe words?

Comment: ^What do you mean? 

I still haven't quite resolved this, and would appreciate any help.